# How can I keep active state when clicking link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know an active element is when you click the link. Is there anyway to carry the active state across to the next page.

Is there anyway to do it via javascript so it removes an active state and adds the active state to the next link. So i'm having a bit of problems with the active state, if anyone can help me out.

Here is the HTML

```
<ul class="list-type">
<li class="active"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul.list-type {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
margin-left: 0;
text-align: left;
font-size: 16px;

}
ul.list-type li {
padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
}
ul.list-type li a {
color: #000;
}
ul.list-type li a:active {
color: #F00;
}
ul.list-type li a:hover {
color: #CCC;
}
```

Here is a JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dDcXC/

Comment: So you want to add the `active` class to the page you are currently on using Javascript?

Comment: Is the transition done via Ajax? Otherwise it's better to just do it using back-end code.

Comment: Try add active class using jquery

Comment: [`:visited`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#the-link-pseudo-classes-link-and-visited)?

Comment: If I click the second link in the list then obviously that would be on a new page with its own list then the active state will be "active" on there, so a javascript solution would be best?

thgaskell :visited is not what i'm looking for as then they would all be highlighted. Its meant to be active on whatever page your currently on.

Comment: you could use focus() from jquery to make it active again

Answer (score 0):

You can get the URL from `document.URL` from there it's as simple as iterating all links and 
comparing their `href`
You can try something like:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i= 0 ; i<links.length ; i++){
 if(links[i].href == document.URL){
    var currentClass = links[i].className;
    links[i].className = currentClass + " active"; 
 }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but cannot seem to get this working on the JS Fiddle before I posted the question here.